# browser-sync (gulp) does not refresh page after modifying sass

Tags: sass, gulp, jhipster, browser-sync

I build application using sass and browser-sync. I generated configuration using jhipster.

When I modify my *.scss file, page does not refresh automatically. Here's part of my *gulpfile.js*:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src(config.scss + '**/*.{scss,sass}')
        .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
        .pipe(changed(config.app + 'assets/styles', {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(sass({includePaths:config.importPath}).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'assets/styles'));
});

gulp.task('styles', ['sass'], function() {
    return gulp.src(config.app + 'assest/styles')
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

File was generated by jhipster also. I have tried every solution found on stackoverflow but nothing worked. Is something wrong with code?

If its necessary I can post whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src(config.scss + '**/*.{scss,sass}')
    .pipe(plumber({errorHandler: handleErrors}))
    .pipe(changed(config.app + 'assets/styles', {extension: '.css'}))
    .pipe(sass({includePaths:config.importPath}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.app + 'assets/styles'));
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}));
});
```

and run task `sass`

Comment: Still nothing. Everything works great when I modify, for example, html file. But when I modify scss file, it is being compiled, but I need to refresh page manually.

Answer (score 0):

[JHipster 2.27.2 release](https://jhipster.github.io/2016/03/07/jhipster-release-2.27.2.html) has fixed some issues with sass and browser-sync.
Try updating JHipster and re-generate your project.